# Time needed to split and combine a large file

Tags: file, time, split

Suppose I have a really large file, for example 10TB, then I would like to archive and split it into several parts for easier transfer using 7-Zip. Suppose I would like to split into n parts, my question is what is the relationship between n and the time needed to split the file?

The larger n is, the more time we need to split it or we need the same amount of time to split whatever number of parts I want?

After the split, I will have to combine these parts to get the original file, now what is the relationship between n and the time needed to combine these n parts?

Comment: How do you split it? What file system? What storage system? etc...

Comment: Why don't you try it and figure this out. The results will be highly dependent on how you're planning on doing it and likely the spec of the machine(s). Are there any other processes that are using disk acces how full is the file/fragmented is the file system, etc. There are too many variables to give you a good answer

Comment: @assylias I am not so sure how to split it...I am doing a theoretical research about data transfer, and in my research I assume we need to split the data for easier transfer. I am not sure about the file system or storage system...How about I suppose that I use 7zip to split the file in Windows 7

Comment: @phuzi I tried myself, seems that the total amount of time needed to do the division does not differ much no matter how many parts I divide the file into. But still could not be certain. Such relationship needs a lot of tests and should be certain statistically, I cannot do it for sure. I just thought there might be some existing test already although I did a lot of research online and could not find any.

Comment: Be aware that transferring large amounts of data can be quicker by courier than the internet depending on network speeds.

Comment: @phuzi I know that. My research focuses on transfering the big data over HPN, and here I suppose I have to divide the big data into several parts.